# Transition probabilities do not sum to $1$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a set of weekly probabilities, and in order to convert to monthly probabilities, I have firstly convert the weekly probabilities into rates, $$r = -\frac{\ln (1-p)}{  t} ,\quad t=1\text{ week.}$$ 
Then from the rates I convert to monthly probabilities, 
$$P = 1 -\exp(-rt),\quad t=4\text{ weeks.}$$ 
Strangely though, these monthly probabilities do not sum up to $1$ for each row!

What has happened? Did I do something wrong?  I hope somebody can help me in explaining my situation.

Comment: You need to reformat this question of yours, and probably add a couple of examples of your data as well.

Comment: Not good enough! Explain why you think going from weekly probabilities to monthly probabilities requires any conversion whatsoever. Explain why you chose this particular conversion. Explain what you mean by `/t,t=1 week`. And of course - reformat your question properly, use LaTex for the mathematical expressions, and put each sentence in a separate line. If you want users to help you with your question, then start by making it easier for them to read it.